# Undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose' with cmake and opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, zlib

I try to build the project, [doppia](https://bitbucket.org/rodrigob/doppia), but linking error occurs. I guess this is a linker error, but I've spent a lot of time and haven't find a working answer.

When I tried before, there is no error. But I have other error about CUDA, so I reinstalled opencv. After that, this linking error occurs.

So, I think this is opencv-related problem such as mistake of path, etc.

**Command:**

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo . && make
```

path .bashrc

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/Documents/Python/imra/code/opencv-2.4.11/release/lib:/home/username/Documents/Python/imra/code/opencv-2.4.11/release/3rdparty/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PKG_CONFIG=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/matterd/Documents/Python/imra/code/opencv-2.4.11/release/unix-install/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

**Output**

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /home/matterd/Documents/Python/imra/code/opencv-2.4.11/release/installed/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o):
>   undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so:
>   error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error:
>   ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [ground_estimation] error 1
>   make[1](https://bitbucket.org/rodrigob/doppia): *** [CMakeFiles/ground_estimation.dir/all

] error 2
make: *** [all] error 2

**some info:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
- OpenCV 2.4.11
- ZLIB 1.2.8

Comment: I found the solution. The error is caused by order of link file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The error is caused by order of link file.

[Compilation problems with ZLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700414/compilation-problems-with-zlib)